# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred with a closure - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Alamofire to make requests to my server and I wrap it within my own LMLAPI struct that has a request function to do this. How can I pass in an optional codable?

My file/struct:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum RouterAPI {
  case menu(restaurantName: String)
  case placesNearby(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
  case placesText(query: String)
  case notifications(token: String)

    var url: String {
    switch self {
    case .menu(let restaurantName):
      return "/restaurant/menu/\(restaurantName)/"
    case .placesNearby:
      return "/google/find-nearby-places/"
    case .placesText:
      return "/google/find-places-text/"
        case .notifications:
            return "/notification/token/"
        }
  }

    var parameters: Parameters? {
    switch self {
    case .menu:
      return nil
    case .placesNearby(let latitude, let longitude):
      return [
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude
      ]
    case .placesText(let query):
      return [
        "query": query
      ]
        case .notifications(let token):
            return [
                "token": token
            ]
        }
  }

}

struct LMLAPI {
  static let sharedInstance = LMLAPI()

  private var connectionProtocol = Environment().configuration(PlistKey.ConnectionProtocol)
  private var serverUrl = Environment().configuration(PlistKey.ServerURL)

    func request<T: Codable>(from endpoint: RouterAPI, mthd method: HTTPMethod, mdl model: T.Type? = nil, vc viewController: UIViewController? = nil, completionHandler: ((T) -> Void)? = nil) {
    viewController?.showActivityIndicator()

        let headers = ["Authorization": "Token adsfasd"]
        let requestUrl = "\(connectionProtocol)://\(serverUrl)\(endpoint.url)"
        Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: method, parameters: endpoint.parameters, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseData { (response) in

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        viewController?.hideActivityIndicator()
      }

      switch response.result {
      case .success:
        print("✅\(method.rawValue)✅ - \(requestUrl)")
      case .failure:
        print("❌\(method.rawValue)❌ - \(requestUrl)")
        return
      }

      do {
        guard let data = response.data else { return }
    guard let model = model else { return }
        guard let completionHandler = completionHandler else { return }

        let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(model, from: data)
        completionHandler(object)

      } catch let error {
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Calling this works:

```
LMLAPI.sharedInstance.request(from: .placesText(query: query), mthd: .get, mdl: Places.self, vc: self) { (places) in
        self.places = places
        self.loadPlaces()
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
LMLAPI.sharedInstance.request(from: RouterAPI.notifications(token: fcmToken), mthd: HTTPMethod.post)
```

Error:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

So far from what I've learned is that it makes sense that the callable function can't be inferred because I'm not passing in the codable struct so the compiler doesn't know what to do, I think? My question is how do I get it to work or what do I need to add/remove to make it so it works? The reason why I'd like it to work is that I don't care to have a codable object return in a closure, in this particular case, as I do with other requests. Thank you.

Comment: The code – a generic constrained to `Codable` with an optional type – makes no sense at all. Look at the Standard Library. There are implementations of multiple methods with the same signature but different constraints so the compiler calls the proper one. Making one method consider all cases with checking types at runtime is pretty *unswifty* and inefficient.

Comment: @vadian are you saying I should create a separate function(s) for a post method, get method, put method, etc.?

Comment: A sort of. Your question is about omitting a generic type in a method signature. This will require type checking inside the method and is discouraged.

Comment: @vadian  oh I understand now. Thanks for your input, might have to re work how I do it entirely then. I tried being ‘dynamic’ but I think I’ve just gotten myself into bad practices perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think There are 2 ways to make it work either:

1. Using function overloading and make 2 function with different parameters one that accept the model type and the other without. (recommended)
2. add default value to the model type that you can test against in the function to discard the encoding part of the function. (not a clean way to solve the problem)

Comment: Thank you. Function overloading seems like the best way for mes